# Trigger the modal on page load for Bootstrap v3.4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

> I have tried various solutions for the same and but I am unable to figure out the correct way. I am not able to know why the output is not coming in desired way.
> I am not able to trigger the modal on page load for Bootstrap v3.4.
> I have added both HTML and JavaScript code.
> The Javascript code is added above the closing body tag.
> The preloader comes first after the opening body tag and followed by the modal.

```
 <body>

    <div class="preloader">
    <div class="loader">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="circle circle-1"></div>
        <div class="circle circle-1a"></div>
        <div class="circle circle-2"></div>
        <div class="circle circle-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">


            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" style="font-size:18px;">Franchise Enquiry Form</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-body scrollable">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="quote-pic">
                      <img src="assets/img/modal/Pop-Up-Form-1.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="quote-item">

                      <form action="process.php" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <select class="form-control" name="brochure_type" required>
                            <option value="">Select Franchise Model</option>
                            <option value="Pre_Schools">Pre-schools</option>
                            <option value="Model_Schools">Model Schools </option>
                            <option value="International_Schools">International Schools</option>

                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" name="name" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="number" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" name="location" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Your Requirements" name="requirement" required />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="default-btn">
                          Submit Now
                        </button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
   

    



 // Triggering modal on page load

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        });
    </script>
     </body>
```

Comment: Your code works.

Comment: But it doesn't work in my system.

Comment: You haven't provided enough details then. If we can't reproduce the issue you're having, we can't help.

Comment: Check now and let me know what type of information should I add further?

Comment: This should be in Bootstrap v3.4

Comment: It's working for me, with your same BS version. Try adding: 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

Check if with a button the modal toggles or not

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the Bootstrap's JavaScript file? I believe jQuery is required too, did you include that as well?

What method do you use to include the Bootstrap / jQuery Javascript files? CDN or npm?

I got it to work using the 3.4.1 Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript CDN, as well as the jQuery 3.6.0 CDN.

[image]

Comment: I want to trigger the modal on page load with Bootstrap v3.4 not by latest versions @Eric

Comment: Yes, I have included both both Bootstrap and JQuery file. In the head section 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">// This Bootsrap is under V3.4

and for JQuery just before closing body tag 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>//This JQuery is under v3.5

Comment: How about the bootstrap JS file? Any errors in the console? It is working for me too with Bootstrap V3.4.